# VSCode regular expression to delete function calls

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, fuzzy-search, automated-refactoring

I need to do a refactor in my code base and I'm trying to do it efficiently using VSCode.

I have a function `foo` and it's curried. I refactored it to get rid of one of its arguments. So currently it's called like this:

```js
foo('string-to-delete')(argToKeep)
```

where the string to delete is some arbitrary string like `'chat'`, `'friends'` etc.

I'm trying to select all calls of foo and the first arguments and replace them with just `foo`, so that I get:

```js
foo(argToKeep)
```

anywhere `foo` is called.

I found a regex that I think matches all square brackets: `/\(([^)]+)\)/`, but I can't get it to work. Here is how I'm trying it.

[image]

How can I use the regex search to remove the first call of a function?

Comment: You added regex delimiters, remove them, `foo\(([^()]+)\)`

Comment: Should it only be strings starting with a single quote?